# Add RequiredFieldValidator to dynamically created control in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a page with some textboxes.  Some of the ASP:Textboxes are made in the .aspx file, and other custom ones are created in codebehind (based on db).  I want to validate to make sure all fields are filled.

When I press my ASP:Button to continue, the textboxes created in my html/aspx file are correctly validated, but for some reason, the dynamically created RequiredFieldValidators are ignored.

Code:

```
                    <tr runat="server" id="weight_row">
                        <td>
                            Weight: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="weightReqLabel" CssClass="required" Visible="false">*</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="weight" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="validator_weight" ControlToValidate="weight" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Required." CssClass="validation-error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The above works correctly.

However, this does not work:

```
TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
txtbx.ID = "TextBox_" + i;
txtbx.CssClass = "form-control";
txtbx.Text = fieldValue;

RequiredFieldValidator reqFieldVal = new RequiredFieldValidator();
reqFieldVal.ID = "validator_" + i;
reqFieldVal.ControlToValidate = txtbx.ID;
reqFieldVal.SetFocusOnError = true;
reqFieldVal.ErrorMessage = "Required";
reqFieldVal.EnableClientScript = false;
reqFieldVal.CssClass = "required";
reqFieldVal.Enabled = true;

placeHolder.Controls.Add(txtbx);
placeHolder.Controls.Add(reqFieldVal);
```

Before I added `EnableClientScript=false`, none of the validation was working.  After I added that, the normally coded validators worked, but the code behind ones do not.

I've also tried to add a ValidationGroup and try Page.Validate in the OnClick of the button but it doesn't seem to help.

```
protected void SaveAndContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            ((Redirect))
        }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
...
placeHolder.Controls.Add(reqFieldVal); 
reqFieldVal.Validate();
...
```

it worked for me

Comment: Sruthi, thanks for the answer! Just a comment since i see you're new to SO. Code can get messy in answers, so we use special formatting so it stands out. I'd recommend instead of saying something like 'before this' or 'after this line', copy those lines to your answer and then append or prepend your additional code. Then highlight it all and use the 'code' formatting option (the brackets {} button .)